# How to implement gradual output of sorted data in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a certain `Training` model. I am trying to upload her documents **step by step** so that the trainings that are closer (by the `start_date`) are uploaded first, and then later trainings. However, I have a problem because this is the code:

```
const future_trainings = await Training.find({
   ...filter,
   id: {$lte: last_training_id},
   start_date: {$gte: cur_time},
   }, 
   requested_training_data,
   {
      sort: {start_date: 1},
      skip: skip,
      limit: limit
});
```

This code does not meet my requirements, but performs, as far as I understand, another action, namely, selects the fragment specified by `limit` & `skip`, and only then performs sorting.

My question is, how do I fix my code so that it works correctly?

I think one of the solutions will be to get the entire list of trainings, then sort it by date, then select the fragment I need, set by `skip` & `limit`, and only then work with it.

Here it is possible to even slightly optimize this process by getting not all the data from the full list of trainings, but only `id` and `start_date`, and then using the `$in` operator to get the desired data segment.

But are there easier ways to solve my problem?